# Garbage Collection - Old Generation

Tags: java

I am learning how garbage collection works.

I am clear with Young generation, but not with Old generation

When old generation is full and major GC is performed then what happens?

Does all objects either live or dead are removed from Old generation or only objects which are dead are removed?

If all objects in old generation are live at the time of major GC then what happens? Does it throws OutOfMemoryError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Young generation**: Most of the newly created objects are located here. Since most objects soon become unreachable, many objects are created in the young generation, then disappear. When objects disappear from this area, we say a "minor GC" has occurred.

**Old generation**: The objects that did not become unreachable and survived from the young generation are copied here. It is generally larger than the young generation. As it is bigger in size, the GC occurs less frequently than in the young generation. When objects disappear from the old generation, we say a "major GC" (or a "full GC") has occurred.

**OldGen** : This pool is basically contain tenured and virtual (reserved) space and will be holding those objects which survived after garbage collection from YoungGen space.

If old generation becomes full, `OOM` will be thrown.

```
Q & A
```

When old generation is full and major gc is performed then what happens? `Objects are removed from memory.`

Does all objects either live or dead are removed from old generation or only objects which are dead are removed? `only dead objects are removed, objects which are still referenced still live in old`

If all objects in old generation are live then what happens?

```
Does it throws OutOfMemoryError? OOM will be thrown
```

Answer (score 1):

Only those objects which are not reachable are removed by GC.
So yes, if all objects in old generation heap are reachable, JVM will throw OutOfMemoeryError.

> **Old generation:** The objects that did not become unreachable and survived from the young generation are copied here. It is generally larger than the young generation. As it is bigger in size, the GC occurs less frequently than in the young generation. When objects disappear from the old generation, we say a "major GC" (or a "full GC") has occurred.

you may look [here](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-java-garbage-collection/) for more details.

Comment: And if i want to remove that error then is there any way by coding?

Comment: There is no way to handle OutOfMemory by coding. Remember, exceptions can be handled but not the errors. But you may configure JVM arguments for the application to get heap dump when application crashes. And you can also tweak heap size of an application so that this scenario doesn't happen in first place.